# simultaneously avoiding a `:dependent => :destroy` and a `ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I understand that when I have associations in my model, I need to add a `dependent: destroy` to the association, e.g:

answer.rb:

```
 has_many :answer_likes, :dependent => :destroy
```

so as to make sure that when an object (e.g, an answer) gets deleted, all associated objects (answer_likes) gets deleted as well.

This helps to avoid this error (or a similar one):

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:
```

On the other hand, if I don't want this error, and I don't want the associated objects (answer_likes) that may be referencing this deleted object (answer) to get deleted as well, what is the recommended way of structuring the association?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the new [Rails 4.2 foreign key](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys) definition, then you don't need to use the `has_many` especially if you don't need to access the associated objects in the main model.

However, the foreign key constraint by default raises an error if you are trying to remove a record that has associated objects.

You can avoid the error by telling the database what it should do in case of a delete, passing the proper option to the [`add_foreigh_key`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key) call. If you pass

```
on_delete: :nullify
```

then the database will allow the deletion of the Answer and will set the foreign key to nil for each AnswerLike. There are other 2 options, `cascade` and `restrict` (which generally is the default).

Comment: Thanks @simone Carletti. I tried to add `on_delete: :nullify` to the front of the association with no success. Then I used it as follow: `dependent: :nullify`. Not working as well. could you expatiate on your explanation? thank you

Comment: `on_delete` is not an association key you can configure on the fly, it's an option you must use when running the migration. Please read again the links I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `before_destroy`

in **Answer** model

```
before_destroy :detach_associated

def detach_associated
  self.answer_likes.update_all(:answer_id => nil)
end
```

In this case the associated records won't get deleted, but will be orphaned.

Well, I don't know how efficient this will be for large number of associated records